# Kotlin Flow as an event loop

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have a Kotlin `Flow<String>` with event names, produced by another thread but ultimately coming in over the network.

I would like to use that to control an event loop, but - as someone new to Kotlin - it feels like I'm misusing it:

```
val commands: SharedFlow<String> = ...
commands.takeWhile { 
  when (command) {
    "foo" -> executeFoo()
    "bar" -> executeBar()
    // ...
  }
  command != "cancel"
}.collect {}
```

I saw that `takeWhile` is built on `collectWhile` which is what I would really like to use, but it's `internal`. Is there any better way to get rid of the `collect {}` or am I completely off track here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it is much cleaner to separate the condition and the action:

```kotlin
commands
    .takeWhile { it != "cancel" }
    .collect {
        when (it) {
            "foo" -> executeFoo()
            "bar" -> executeBar()
            // ...
        }
    }
```

This is probably why `collectWhile` is internal. In a regular code it should be avoided anyway.